# How does a heated object lose thermal energy in a perfect vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, electrons, momentum

Suppose I heat up an arbitrary object to an arbitrary temp and then place it in a near perfect vacuum (let’s assume inter-galactic space). If there is essentially nothing for the object to transfer its thermal energy to does it lose it, over time, to EM emissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - in a vacuum, the heat loss is via *radiation*, typically visible light and/or infrared radiation.